# How to use Tkcalendar virtual events?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkcalendar

Still I’m confused on that tkcalendar virtual events usage to bind user actions on the calendar days selections. Making something like follow,

```
calendar.bind("<<CalendarSelected>>", print(calendar.get_date())
```

That print the default date once the I run the script but when I select on the displayed calendar nothing is printed. Normally any selection on any day on the calendar should be printed if was really bound. I did something wrong right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a lambda function instead

```
calendar.bind("<<CalendarSelected>>", lambda: print(calendar.get_date())
```

You code will currently bind the result of the print function as the callback for the bind. Since print returns None, no function will be called.

A lambda creates an anonymous function.

If your code gets more complex than a single line, put this code in to a function of its own and use the name of that function in the bind method, for example

```
calendar.bind("<<CalendarSelected>>", showDateToUser)
```

Comment: A new question would be best if you are changing the scope of the question. Mark this one as answered.

Comment: @PrinceD.Taylor There is a tick next to the answer below the vote up/vote down buttons. Click that

Comment: You missed a ')' at the end of the first piece of code ;)

Also, that lambda function needs a parameter, so it would be:

`calendar.bind("<<CalendarSelected>>", lambda event: print(calendar.get_date()))`